# NAutowired in AOP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My goal is to inject HttpContextAccessor to my logger for what I use Metalama. The logging part is ok, it's working. But now I want to make my code more cleaner, later more generic. For that I need to get access for HttpContextAccessor. Since I can't use DI in Metalama OverrideMethodAspect derived class, I found [this](https://github.com/kirov-opensource/NAutowired) great library that will allow me to inject the value using filed injector. In the sample app it works fine, even if I split the code in Service and Repository layer. I can access the HttpContextAccessor.
But in my project I can't get the instance of HttpContextAccessor injectedd to my property. It is always null.
My idea was to wrap the interfaces I need in a class, use NAutowired field injector to inject the desired classes and then use the instance of the class in the OverrideMethodAspect  override method.

```
[Service]
public class ServiceFactory
{
    [Autowired(typeof(HttpContextAccessor))]
    public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }
}

public class LoggingAttribute : OverrideMethodAspect
{
    public override dynamic OverrideMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();
            var result = meta.Proceed();

            
            var user = (serviceFactory.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "uid");
            var loggedInUserIdentity = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.Value) ?
                                       $" => by user: {user.Value}" :
                                       string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the HttpContextAccessor in serviceFactory is always null.
I changed the startup class to, as showed in example.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseSerilog();
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices();

builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IControllerActivator, NAutowiredControllerActivator>());
var assemblies = new List<string>
{
    "aaa.Web.Api",
    "aaa.Core",
    "aaa.Comon"
};
builder.Services.AutoRegisterDependency(assemblies);
```

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 6 and after,

Create ServiceTool class,

```
public static class ServiceTool
{
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        public static IServiceCollection Create(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            return services;
        }
}
```

Create extension for registering service tool in program.cs pipeline,

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddDependencyResolvers(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
            return ServiceTool.Create(services);
        }
    }
```

After these, you have to register it in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDependencyResolvers();
```

After these steps, you can access `HttpContextAccessor` object everywhere in your app by using;

```
var httpContextAccessor = ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but that is not what I need. I need to inject my services without DI.

Comment: I answered. You can use ServiceTool static class to get object without DI.

Answer (score 0):

The key is:

```cs
   var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();
```

If you want to inject an instance of the `ServiceFactory` class via dependency, then the `ServiceFactory` itself should also inject the instance via dependency, if you use `new` to create the instance, then the container will not work.
You should inject `ServiceFactory` instance in `LoggingAttribute`:

```cs
[Service]
public class LoggingAttribute : OverrideMethodAspect
{
    [Autowired]
    public ServiceFactory serviceFactory;
    public override dynamic OverrideMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = meta.Proceed();

            
            var user = (serviceFactory.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "uid");
            var loggedInUserIdentity = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.Value) ?
                                       $" => by user: {user.Value}" :
                                       string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the `LoggingAttribute` instance should also be injected into the controller in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I can't use DI in Metalama OverrideMethodAspect derived class

Yes you can:

```
[IntroduceDependency]
private readonly ILogger? logger;
```